# FTP commands in batch file

Tags: unix, batch-file, ftp

I have a FTP script to move files between servers. However the script with mput does not transfer the files. If I use put it does transfer. Am I missing something.?
Here is the code that I have

```
user >ftp.dat
pwd >>ftp.dat
cd server1/home >>ftp.dat
prompt >>ftp.dat
mput test1 test2 >>ftp.dat
quit>> ftp.dat
ftp -n -s:ftp.dat server2
del ftp.dat
```

The following works:

```
user >ftp.dat
pwd >>ftp.dat
cd server1/home >>ftp.dat
prompt >>ftp.dat
put test1 >>ftp.dat
put test2 >>ftp.dat
quit>> ftp.dat
ftp -n -s:ftp.dat server2
del ftp.dat
```

Comment: Does `mput test*` work?

Comment: Please take the redirection, `>>ftp.dat`, off of the mput line and post the results. What does the ftp `-i` switch do?

Comment: Show us the contents of `ftp.dat`.